# Grouping from Json data, which contain array of dictionaries in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4.1

I've local json file, which contains array of dictionaries. I want to group based on key name from below json. Means same name in one group. Please tell me how can I achieve that. Thank you.

Json Data:

[
  {
    "name": "Abc",
    "number": 123,
    "marks": 78
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz",
    "number": 456,
    "marks": 50
  },
  {
    "name": "Abc",
    "number": 789,
    "marks": 78
  }
]

Code:

[code and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07cyl.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "group"? Do you mean sort them by name value?

Comment: I mean same name value at one side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[init(grouping:by:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init)

You should return value of name key in the closure.

```
 let arr = [ [ "name": "Abc", "number": 123, "marks": 78 ], [ "name": "xyz", "number": 456, "marks": 50 ], [ "name": "Abc", "number": 789, "marks": 78 ] ]
 let dict = Dictionary(grouping: arr) { $0["name"] as! String }
 print(dict)

//["Abc": [["name": "Abc", "number": 123, "marks": 78], ["name": "Abc", "number": 789, "marks": 78]], "xyz": [["name": "xyz", "number": 456, "marks": 50]]]
```

Comment: I did same. I am getting error. What is wrong in my code? Can you please identify.

Comment: @user3516627 Declare the real dictionary type of the content of your array, not `Any`, and this solution will work.

Comment: I am not able to pull data from that. I mean how can I pull values from each collection ("Abc" and "xyz") and operate on the members of that particular group and store it at one place in array or something like this.